# add_image_size crop position not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to hard crop images (315px by 600px) on my custom theme WordPress site so that the left top of the image appears on my main page (and the full image is used on the individual post pages). However, the images still appear centered. In my functions file I am using:

```
function invadingholland_setup() {

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size('post-cartoon', 200, 200, array('left', 'top'));

} 

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'invadingholland_setup');
```

...and in my loop I am using:

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-cartoon'); ?></a>
</div>
```

... and then this CSS around it:

```
.post-thumbnail {
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
text-align: left;
border: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000;
}
```

...and I've tried regenerating all my images. If I play around with the sizes in my add_image_size code I do see a change but noting changes if I put different values into the array. I've also confirmed with my hoster that I have php-gd.

And just to make things even stranger it works as it should on my local test server on my laptop but not on the real site.

I'm stomped as to why it is not working. Am I missing a java script? Is it a wordpress setting? Can anyone help? An example of the problem can be seen here: http://www.invadingholland.com in my top two posts.

Thanks

Comment: 1. This is JavaScript, not CSS. 2. This isn't native JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I did not realize this was the case since I know very little about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**Try hooking** it through a function to the **`after_setup_theme`** hook.

```
function mkwilson_setup_theme() {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
   add_image_size( 'post-cartoon', 200, 200, array('left', 'top') );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mkwilson_setup_theme' );
```

Also check that you are calling your post thumbnail correctly in the loop.

**One More note:**

```
add_image_size('post-cartoon', 200, 200, array('left', 'top'), true);
```

The true in the end is not necessary because when you have mentioned the array with left and top it means the image will be hard cropped 200px wide and 200px tall

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that that is what I already have (if I'm understanding it correctly):

Comment: So, you have used it with the hook? And also are you using the correct name in your post loop?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to copy my code into the first comment but something went wrong. I'm still seeing if I can get it to show up right :)

Comment: I had to add it in another answer and then it only half worked. Weird. Sorry about this.

Comment: Ok. got it. you can remove that from your answer. I can see that the images are getting cropped. So your code is fine. And I guess it is correct. Did you check with original images?

Comment: Yeah. I've tried regeneration my images with a plug in and re-uploading the images with a new name but neither way seems to have any affect.If I'm supposed to see a cropped version of the image in my media library I don't see that either.

Comment: Can you share the links of uncropped version of  first 4 images used on your website. Maybe I can have a look at them to verify if the crop is working or not

Comment: I guess you have used this plugin. But in case not -  please use it to regenerate all your images https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Yeah. that's the one I have used.

Comment: I missed your comment asking for the uncropped images. I only have two so far that I have tried it with: http://i2.wp.com/www.invadingholland.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/inv_five_ways_to_fake_speaking_dutch.jpg and http://i2.wp.com/www.invadingholland.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/inv_redesign.jpg Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The first two images are also getting cropped from center then. I can see it in the image. So, all your images are getting cropped at center.

Comment: Does that mean my add image size code is not working? OR could I have some wordpress setting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It took a while but I found out what it was. The Photon module that is part of Jetpack was somehow forcing things to crop from the center. As soon as I turned it off the image was cropped from the left as it is supposed to be.